# Position of graph through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm confused at the position of the graph chart.
I have research and most of the position is through `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects`.

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("J2").Left, _
Top:=Range("J2").Top, _
Width:=Range("J2:M12").Width, _
Height:=Range("J2:M12").Height).Chart
.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
.SetSourceData Source:=Range("B3:C12"), _
PlotBy:=xlColumns
.HasLegend = False
End With
```

I want to position my chart at Row 1 to Row 41 and at Col D to Col AC. By taking inspiration from the code above, I want to plot the graph according to the dimension stated from Col `D1:D41` and from `AC1:AC41`, but I have trouble plotting to it.

```
Dim cht As Shape
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=Range("D1").Left,, _
    Width:=Range("D1:AC1").Width, Height:=Range("").Height)
With cht.Chart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "X VS Y"
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
End With
```

Comment: Just use the same range for all the properties.

Comment: Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=Range("D1:AC1").Left, Top:=Range("D1:AC1").Top, Width:=Range("D1:AC1").Width, Height:=Range("D1:AC1").Height). I use this, but i needed to extend the graph out such as it is really tiny. I just need to adjust the size vertically. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Use `D1:AC41` as the range...

Comment: I did! but i need to stretch the graph out vertically downwards to see the graph

Comment: No, you didn't. You used `D1:AC1`.

Comment: My bad! It works, thank you